# cannot install web3 for python

Tags: visual-c++, pip, web3py

i wanted to install web3py using pip but it gives me errors
in one of the errors it says to install visual c++ 2014 but i already have it on my windows i thought maybe if I create a virtual env it fixes it but it didn't
any idea what is wrong?
by the way I am using python3.9.6

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'e:\programming\python\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\dark knigt\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u076o94s\\bitarray_111d2831f9c54120bd3f0dd15ec559f2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\dark knigt\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u076o94s\\bitarray_111d2831f9c54120bd3f0dd15ec559f2\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\dark knigt\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q0553zy8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'e:\programming\python\venv\include\site\python3.9\bitarray'
         cwd: C:\Users\dark knigt\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u076o94s\bitarray_111d2831f9c54120bd3f0dd15ec559f2\
    Complete output (13 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray
    copying bitarray\test_bitarray.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray
    copying bitarray\test_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray
    copying bitarray\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray
    copying bitarray\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray
    running build_ext
    building 'bitarray._bitarray' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'e:\programming\python\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\dark knigt\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u076o94s\\bitarray_111d2831f9c54120bd3f0dd15ec559f2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\dark knigt\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u076o94s\\bitarray_111d2831f9c54120bd3f0dd15ec559f2\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\dark knigt\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q0553zy8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'e:\programming\python\venv\include\site\python3.9\bitarray' Check the logs for full command output.
```